# Updating the image in laravel 8 clears out the rest of the data in the form

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am working on a laravel 8 project, am using Vue and Inertia when i try to update an image it clears the rest of the data in the form. But if i update the the form without updating the image it works fine. I can create a new record with an image i find that only when i try to update the image that's when this happens

Input field looks like this

```
<input type="file" class="h-full w-full" @input="form.image = $event.target.files[0]">
```

And this is my vue

```
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout";

export default {
    name: "Edit",
    props:{
        errors: Object,
        product: Object,
        productTypes: Object,
    },
    components: {AppLayout},
    data(){
        return {
            form: this.$inertia.form({
                name: this.product.name,
                product_type_id: this.product.product_type_id,
                url: this.product.url,
                status_id: this.product.status_id,
                image: this.product.image
            })
        }
    },
    methods:{
        update() {
            this.form.put(this.route('product.update', this.product.id))
        },
    }
}
```

And below is my update method in the controller

```
public function update(UpdateProductRequest $request, Product $product)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $image = Image::make($file);
            $path = storage_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'products'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $file_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            if ($image->height() == $image->width() && $image->height() > 1080) {
                $image->resize(1080, 1080);
                $image->save($path.$file_name);
            } else {
                $blur = Image::make($file)->fit(1080, 1080)->blur(20);
                $image->resize(1080, 1080, function ($c) {
                    $c->aspectRatio();
                    $c->upsize();
                });

                $blur->insert($image, 'center');
                $blur->save($path.$file_name);
            }

            $product->image = 'products'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file_name;
        }

        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->product_type_id = $request->product_type_id;
        $product->url = $request->url;
        $product->status_id = $request->status_id;
        $product->save();

        return Redirect::route('product.index');
    }
```

I even tried this

```
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
export default {
    name: "Create",
    props:{
        errors: Object,
        product: Object,
        productTypes: Object,
    },
    setup (props) {
        const form = useForm({
            name: props.product.name,
            image: props.product.image,
            url: props.product.url,
            product_type_id: props.product.product_type_id,
            status_id: props.product.status_id
        })
        function submit() {
            form.patch('/product/'+props.product.id)
        }
        return { form, submit }
    }
}
```

when i submit the form it fails validation saying name, product_type_id, url, and status_id is required even if i didn't change them i just changed the image

Comment: Please share us what have you tried and your code.

Comment: @KevinYobeth i've updated my post

Comment: I believe the issue is patch doesn't set the form multipart type like post does? read the last paragraph https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads

Comment: @alex i solved it by adding `preserveState: true`  to  options